# How to unsubscribe Facebook Chatbot app from a page?

Tags: facebook, chatbot

May I know how to unsubscribe Facebook Chatbot app from a page using url request?

I have created a Facebook Chatbot app and subscribed it on a page, now I want to unsubscribe it, I tried using DELETE url request method to "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=my_page_access_token" and return this:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "link": "https://apps.facebook.com/mychatbotappid",
   "name": "myChatbotApplicationName",
   "id": "mychatbotappid"
  }
 ]
}
```

When I test it again on the Messenger, the Chatbot is still there, it wasn't unsubscribe.

It there anything that I have done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like you made a GET request, and not actually a DELETE one.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! You are absolutely right, it's actually not a DELETE request, have found some mistake in my code. I have updated the code and it works perfect now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get data returned like this, it looks like you made a GET request, and not actually a DELETE one.

So using DELETE should “fix” this, and make it work as expected.

---

(In environments that don’t support DELETE requests, one can also make a normal GET request and specify the API method to use via an additional parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#largerequests)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!